# Dynamic UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm having trouble implementing dynamic UITableView inside UIScrollView, without sitting fixed height constraints to the UITableView it disappears and I don't want to make fixed height to it because it is receiving data from API and I don't know the count of them. What I want to achieve is the height of the UITableView should be dynamic not the UITableViewCell.

Here is my code:

**RecipesDetailsView:**

```
class RecipesDetailsView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.scrollView {
            ingredientsTableView.isScrollEnabled = (self.scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 200)
        }

        if scrollView == self.ingredientsTableView {
            self.ingredientsTableView.isScrollEnabled = (ingredientsTableView.contentOffset.y > 0)
        }
    }

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .customVeryLightGray()
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
//        scrollView.bounces = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var recipeTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let recipeTitleLabel = UILabel()
        recipeTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        recipeTitleLabel.text = "Myanmar Traditional Fish Curry"
        recipeTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 25)
        recipeTitleLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        recipeTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        recipeTitleLabel.textAlignment = .left
        return recipeTitleLabel
    }()

    lazy var recipeImage: UIImageView = {
        let recipeImage = UIImageView()
        recipeImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        recipeImage.clipsToBounds = true
        recipeImage.image = UIImage(named: "pizza")
        recipeImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        recipeImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        recipeImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return recipeImage
    }()

    lazy var instructionLabel: UILabel = {
        let instructionLabel = UILabel()
        instructionLabel.text = "Instructions"
        instructionLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        instructionLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        instructionLabel.textAlignment = .left
        instructionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return instructionLabel
    }()

    lazy var instructionsTextView: UITextView = {
        let instructionsTextView = UITextView()
        instructionsTextView.text = "Myanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmarMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar Traditional Fish CurryMyanmar"
        instructionsTextView.textColor = .customLightDarkGray()
        instructionsTextView.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        instructionsTextView.textAlignment = .left
        instructionsTextView.isEditable = false
        instructionsTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        instructionsTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return instructionsTextView
    }()

    lazy var ingredientsLabel: UILabel = {
        let ingredientsLabel = UILabel()
        ingredientsLabel.text = "Ingredients"
        ingredientsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        ingredientsLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        ingredientsLabel.textAlignment = .left
        ingredientsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return ingredientsLabel
    }()

    lazy var buyingIngredientsButton: UIButton = {
        let buyingIngredientsButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        buyingIngredientsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        buyingIngredientsButton.setTitle("Start buying", for: .normal)
        buyingIngredientsButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        buyingIngredientsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 12)
        return buyingIngredientsButton
    }()

    lazy var numberOfGredientsLabel: UILabel = {
        let numberOfGredientsLabel = UILabel()
        numberOfGredientsLabel.text = "Ingredients"
        numberOfGredientsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        numberOfGredientsLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        numberOfGredientsLabel.textAlignment = .left
        numberOfGredientsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return numberOfGredientsLabel
    }()

    lazy var ingredientsTableView: UITableView = {
        let ingredientsTableView = UITableView()
        ingredientsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ingredientsTableView.delegate = self
        ingredientsTableView.dataSource = self
        ingredientsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        ingredientsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        ingredientsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0
        ingredientsTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
        ingredientsTableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
        ingredientsTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        ingredientsTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        ingredientsTableView.backgroundColor = .white
        ingredientsTableView.bounces = true
        ingredientsTableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        ingredientsTableView.register(IngredientsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "IngredientsTableViewCell")
        ingredientsTableView.frame.size.height = ingredientsTableView.contentSize.height
        return ingredientsTableView
    }()

    func setupScrollViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1)
        ])
    }

    func setupRecipeTitleLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            recipeTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            recipeTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            recipeTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
        recipeTitleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(240.0), for: .horizontal)
        recipeTitleLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(740.0), for: .horizontal)
    }

    func setupRecipeImageConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            recipeImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recipeTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            recipeImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            recipeImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            recipeImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height / 4)
        ])
    }

    func setupInstructionsLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            instructionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recipeImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            instructionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            instructionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }

    func setupInstructionsTextViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            instructionsTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: instructionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            instructionsTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            instructionsTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }

    func setupIngredientsLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ingredientsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: instructionsTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            ingredientsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        ])
    }

    func setupBuyingIngredientsButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buyingIngredientsButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ingredientsLabel.centerYAnchor),
            buyingIngredientsButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }

    func setupNumberOfIngredientsLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            numberOfGredientsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ingredientsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            numberOfGredientsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),

        ])
    }

    func setupIngredientsTableViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ingredientsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfGredientsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            ingredientsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            ingredientsTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            ingredientsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
//            ingredientsTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ingredientsTableView.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubViews() {
        addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(recipeTitleLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(recipeImage)
        containerView.addSubview(instructionLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(instructionsTextView)
        containerView.addSubview(ingredientsLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(buyingIngredientsButton)
        containerView.addSubview(numberOfGredientsLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(ingredientsTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubViews()
        setupScrollViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupRecipeTitleLabelConstraints()
        setupRecipeImageConstraints()
        setupInstructionsLabelConstraints()
        setupInstructionsTextViewConstraints()
        setupIngredientsLabelConstraints()
        setupBuyingIngredientsButtonConstraints()
        setupNumberOfIngredientsLabelConstraints()
        setupIngredientsTableViewConstraints()
    }
}

extension RecipesDetailsView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IngredientsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientsTableViewCell
        cell.theNumberOfIngredient.text = "1"
        cell.theNameOfIngredient.text = "Tomato"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension

    }

}
```

**IngredientsTableViewCell:**

```
class IngredientsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
//        selectionStyle = .none
//        self.backgroundColor = .white

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var theNumberOfIngredient: UILabel = {
        let theNumberOfIngredient = UILabel()
        theNumberOfIngredient.text = "Ingredients"
        theNumberOfIngredient.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        theNumberOfIngredient.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        theNumberOfIngredient.textAlignment = .left
        theNumberOfIngredient.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return theNumberOfIngredient
    }()

    lazy var theNameOfIngredient: UILabel = {
        let theNameOfIngredient = UILabel()
        theNameOfIngredient.text = "Ingredients"
        theNameOfIngredient.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        theNameOfIngredient.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        theNameOfIngredient.textAlignment = .left
        theNameOfIngredient.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return theNameOfIngredient
    }()

    func setupTheNumberOfIngredientConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theNumberOfIngredient.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            theNumberOfIngredient.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupTheNameOfIngredientConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theNameOfIngredient.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theNumberOfIngredient.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            theNameOfIngredient.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theNumberOfIngredient.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(theNumberOfIngredient)
        addSubview(theNameOfIngredient)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupTheNumberOfIngredientConstraints()
        setupTheNameOfIngredientConstraints()
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, this is the wrong approach, I think you should create UITableView with grouped style and in `the section 0` add your custom UI and `the section 1` apply `IngredientsTableViewCell` with the data From API.

otherwise, you can set static height for UITableView Mathematically.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about that approach before.